# How to get rid of the page title at the top left of each page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I am looking for a way to hide or get rid of the page title at the top left of each page. I do not want to use JavaScript to do so.

For clarification - I want to hide or get rid of the thing outlined in red here:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to hide from all pages or one page?

Comment: I want to hide it from all pages without using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your custom Master Page design file (.html file) and remove the Page Title Snippet.

You can search with keyword "pageTitle" and remove the related snippet.

Here is snippet you have to remove.

```
<h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle">
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageSiteName" class="ms-core-navigation" runat="server">-->
    <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle1">-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>-->
    <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)-->Default Publishing Site<!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPLinkButton>-->
    <!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
</h1>
```

Comment: This is definitely the best option - very little chance of corrupting your master page and also very easy to do. Just ctrl+f "h1" and you should immediately find the portion that you need to delete.

Comment: Yes. Every portion of the design file is a snippet which can be easy to manage.

Comment: Is there a way to change the navigation bar from the Master Page design file? I would like to make changes to the font-size and possibly even add pictures along with the text.

Comment: You can get a customized snippet using design manager and replace with one you have in your design file. But I recommend any design related changes manage with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If this needs to be removed on single page then drop the Content Editor Web Part and reference the CSS mentioned in that thread in your web part and that should do the trick.

For global changes you can edit your Master page and reference your CSS file in there.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="HidePageTitleCSS" Name="PATHTOYOURCSS" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
```

Answered here:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/198beae2-e39b-4fe9-abde-f375da490fea/sharepoint-2013-how-to-hide-or-remove-title-from-home-page-of-a-public-facing-website?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: I **DO NOT** recommend trying this. If you add this snippet of code to the HTML page that updates your master page then you will break your site and you must revert to the working master page somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This seems easy enough. Just add a Script editor web part in your page and add below script to hide the title.

```
<style type="text/css">
h1#pageTitle {
display :none;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: While this may work for an individual page, I was looking for an answer that would get rid of the page title on all pages, and that is why I accepted Venkat's solution.

Comment: Absouely, for all pages in your site, you can use in master page. Actually I have faced this scenario where I dont want to loose page title information for all pages in my site. So I did this page wise as and when required :)

Comment: Yes it is definitely helpful to know how to get rid of the page title on just the one page. That is why I gave you +1.